# I get "Function called outside component initialization" when using an npm library

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have written and published a svelte library that makes the form validation library vest easy to use with svelte. I have thoroughly tested it, and it works great, also with a local path dependency. But as soon as I import the library from npm I get this error:

> **Function called outside component initialization**

I'm pretty sure the function in question is `setContext()`. The thing is... I'm sure it's not called outside component initialization, and if I just copy the source of the .ts file into my project it works again.

I assume that somehow they have access to different svelte versions, and that's what's causing the mixup. But I don't see how it's possible, because I don't have svelte as a dependency, only as a peer dependency (I also tried removing it from `peerDependencies` but that didn't change anything).

Here is the repo: [https://github.com/enyo/use-vest](https://github.com/enyo/use-vest/tree/f5c85db3583b51b5b2bd0608ca5cfe3b1f285591)

Here is repo that can replicate the issue: https://github.com/enyo/use-vest-repro

Comment: A full call stack might be helpful as that may show the source of the problem. Also, how the code is built, if applicable. (Few people will be willing to clone and build a repository just to answer a question. Questions in general should be entirely self-contained.)

Comment: Here is a link to the issue https://github.com/sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/issues/360

Answer (score 1):

After some debugging I found that error:
`Function called outside component initialization`
only happens on the dev server, on the client and production build the library works as expected.

This is because on the server the setContext is imported from different runtimes.

On the server the `setContext` inside the Form.svelte is included from "svelte/index.js" but in "use-vest/dist/index.js"  the `setContext` is included from "svelte/index.mjs"

.js vs  .**m**js

For H.B. the call stacks:

```
Trace: js
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Volumes/Sites/use-vest-repro/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.js:987:9)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:827:12)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:170:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:198:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:409:24)
    at async importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:435:15)
```

```
Trace: mjs
    at file:///Volumes/Sites/use-vest-repro/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.mjs:984:9
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:198:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:409:24)
    at async importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:435:15)
    at async nodeImport (/Volumes/Sites/use-vest-repro/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-59dc6e00.js:59403:21)
    at async eval (/src/lib/components/Form.svelte:7:31)
    at async instantiateModule (/Volumes/Sites/use-vest-repro/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-59dc6e00.js:59333:9)
```

I'm not sure how to solve this...
Let me know if you find a solution.

Comment: The library is built with Rollup, so anything that is being referenced will be included in the output by default. A plugin like [`rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external) could probably be used to make sure that the Svelte code is not bundled.

Comment: The bundle didnt contain svelte,  its the svelte package that contains two versions

Comment: Oh, you are right, it is not packaged. Then I would guess that the server somehow falsely assumes the wrong mode even though the `type` is specified to be `module`...

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: All of this is wrong**

---

The problem is that you can't do a `setContext()` outside of a Svelte component, you need to call it explicitly in the `<script>` tag. The reason it works when you copy and paste it into the component is that the Svelte compiler can associate the component with the given context.

In short, you can't use `setContext()` outside a `.svelte` file.

Hence, a way to solve this problem is to export an actual `.svelte` file (e.g. a `<VestForm>` component). However, there might be another way of going about it better suited to your specific use case, but I'm not sure since I'm not familiar with Vest.

I think the version of Svelte has nothing to do with your issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You _can_ call setContect outside of a Svelte component as long as you call the setContect during component initialization.

Comment: Whoops I just did a test and you're right. Sorry.